At what point in the interrupt-processing path does device-driver code execute?
I am new to interrupt handlers and device i/o and I have a few questions:
When you load a device-driver, i.e. kernel module, its assembly code is stored in the module-mapping region of the Kernel Virtual Address Space. (See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt)
Interrupt Vector Tables (IVT) contain addresses of Interrupt-Service Routines (ISR) which are commonly split into Top-Half and Bottom-Half handlers with the latter being more elaborate, and the physical address of the former being stored in the <Interrupt Vector: ISR> IVT stored in Flash memory (separate from RAM). Often the top-half handler calls the bottom half handler for further processing (I assume by jumping to some other physical address).
Is the bottom-half handler that is jumped to simply some code from the device-driver loaded into the kernel VAS, i.e. in RAM? If yes, how is the address of driver code available to code in flash memory? Are device drivers solely used for machine->device communication? At what point in the interrupt-processing path does device-driver code execute and for what purpose?
My understanding of the interrupt processing path is as follows:

Device sends an IRQ (electrical signal) when its internal state (stored in device registers/buffers) is in a condition that requires servicing (handling) by the host machine. This is often an MSI packet sent over a PCIe bus that contains an Interrupt Vector specifying the interrupt type. For example, on-device sensors may change the device state to one that necessitates external servicing and trigger the send of an MSI packet to host machine.

MSI packet (containing the Interrupt Vector) reaches the APIC attached to a cpu core. The APIC may have its own APIC driver that provides a canned Interrupt Vector which is used to retrieve the address of the ISR and store it in the CPU PC (thus beginning the switch to interrupt context, and CPU part of interrupt handling)

Top-Half interrupt handler begins execution, may call the bottom half handler for further processing.

???? Results of bottom half handler are copied-to-user by code in the device-driver kernel addresses ????



"IVT" is an x86 term, applicable only to real mode.  As part of booting, the kernel will switch to 32 or 64-bit mode (if it wasn't already in 64-bit for an EFI boot) and create an IDT in RAM (interrupt descriptor table), and use the lidt instruction to tell the CPU what address to look for it.  So the kernel does have control of interrupt-handler addresses.

@PeterCordes To confirm - there's a cpu register filled by lidt that contains the physical address in RAM of the newly created IDT. (and a bottom-half handler is code in a device driver that may eventually be jumped to in the interrupt-processing path)

Yes, check the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lgdt:lidt .  But actually linear address not physical.  If paging is enabled, IDT access uses virtual addresses.  (64-bit mode requires that paging is enabled.)  So you can use the same pointer with lidt you were using to store to the IDT.

A Linux bottom half is basically just a task scheduled by the scheduler at some later point.  By the time it runs, the actual handler for the hardware interrupt has completed.  (And maybe returned to whatever user-space task was interrupted, or maybe the bottom half gets scheduled right away, but either way it tells the hardware interrupt controller that we're done handling the interrupt.)

Thank you for your answers. However, I do not know what linear address means here. Does it just mean an physical address shifted by some offset (as in Kernel logical addresses)?
I imagine the lidt instruction will be used by some .s kernel boot procedure asm code. Does your last sentence imply that after the boot process is finished for a 64 bit system with paging enabled, the  64-bit IDTR/GDTR contains this "linear adress" for future lookups? Will a jmp to this address by some kernel code begin interrupt handler execution?

A linear address is a virtual address when paging is enabled.  How are segment registers involved in memory address translation? .  A jmp by some kernel code using the same address you put in the IDT could indeed reach the handler code, but unless you pushed some values on the stack first to match what hardware does when processing an interrupt, you wouldn't really be beginning IRQ handler execution.

@PeterCordes "A Linux bottom half is basically just a task scheduled by the scheduler at some later point. By the time it runs, the actual handler for the hardware interrupt has completed." ---> i.e., top-half handlers run with interrupts off and thus always complete. Bottom-half handlers may be called at the end of the top-half, but execution of this code may be interrupted (causing context switch to some top-half by looking into the IDT) and so bottom halves may be scheduled at a later time?

Understood. You're trying to say that "IRQ handler Execution" is a procedure that requires execution of the IRQ handler code (which in turn is dependent on certain registers having certain values in them, filled in by hardware)

On x86, the hardware pushes interrupt return info (and for some exceptions an error code) onto the stack.  (After switching to the kernel stack as specified in the TSS.)  Other than a page fault modifying CR2 (with the fault address), x86 interrupts don't modify registers (other than the stack pointer).  Other ISAs work differently, e.g. MIPS I think does put something in GPRs, or maybe I'm misremembering and the ABI just leaves two GPRs free for the kernel to clobber asynchronously so it has spare regs in interrupt handlers.

okay, I got the gist. Thank you!

Final question: Interrupt return info == pre-interruption cpu execution context. If a user-process execution was interrupted, the process context is (at the earliest) restored when top-half execution completes. If bottom-half handler execution is interrupted, the cpu register values in interrupt context are also pushed to the kernel stack?
Where would these details be documented besides source code?
